# Subtract a constant number from a column

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I have two large files (~10GB) as follows:

**file1.csv**

```
name,id,dob,year,age,score
Mike,1,2014-01-01,2016,2,20
Ellen,2, 2012-01-01,2016,4,35
.
.
```

**file2.csv**

```
id,course_name,course_id
1,math,101
1,physics,102
1,chemistry,103
2,math,101
2,physics,102
2,chemistry,103
.
.
```

I want to subtract 1 from the "id" columns of these files:

**file1_updated.csv**

```
name,id,dob,year,age,score
Mike,0,2014-01-01,2016,2,20
Ellen,0, 2012-01-01,2016,4,35
```

**file2_updated.csv**

```
id,course_name,course_id
0,math,101
0,physics,102
0,chemistry,103
1,math,101
1,physics,102
1,chemistry,103
```

I have tried `awk '{print ($1 - 1) "," $0}' file2.csv`, but did not get the correct result:

```
-1,id,course_name,course_id
0,1,math,101
0,1,physics,102
0,1,chemistry,103
1,2,math,101
1,2,physics,102
1,2,chemistry,103
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've added an extra column in your attempt. Instead set your first field `$1` to `$1-1`:

```
 awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$1=$1-1;print $0}' file2.csv
```

That semicolon separates the commands. We set the delimiter to comma (`-F","`) and the Output Field Seperator to comma `BEGIN{OFS=","}`. The first command to subtract 1 from the first field executes first, then the print command executes second, so the entire record, `$0`, will now contain the new `$1` value when it's printed.

It might be helpful to only subtract 1 from records that are not your header. So you can add a condition to the first command:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR>1{$1=$1-1} {print $0}' file2.csv
```

Now we only subtract when the record number (`NR`) is greater than 1. Then we just print the entire record.

Comment: Thanks, but `awk '{$1=$1-1;print $0}' file2.csv' only outputs the first column subtracted by 1. I need all the columns in the output.

Comment: My bad. I have updated the script to change the input field separator to comma as well as the output field separator

Comment: Thanks @JNevill. You saved my day ;)